# "Try to write as it is mentioned in the passage."

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

I wrote "robustus" (a type of dinosaurs), and the examiner corrected me as "R. robustus" and commented:"Try to write as it is mentioned in the passage."

does that mean "try to write robustus as same as it is mentioned in the passage."?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the examiner's comment, I am inferring that there is a passage of text that your answer is based on. The examiner is saying when talking about things mentioned in the provided text, use the same naming convention.

For example, if the passage talked about a character named "William Jones", don't then refer to him as "Bill J." in any of your answers that talk about him. Call him what he is called in the passage.